# SimpleCursorAdapter/ArrayAdapter populating database and filtering listview

Tags: android, database, listview

I just got lost. I'm populating database using `SimpleCursorAdapter` to `listview`. I'd like to filter it with `EditText`, but every question/code/example/tutorial is simply not working for me. But I've seen many using `ArrayAdapter`.The question is that, can I populate listview with a `SimpleCursorAdapter` and them filter it using `EditText` with an `ArrayAdapter`?

Answer (score -1):

You must use filter method for filter with edittext.Like above,

```
    kisiText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            if(s.toString().isEmpty()){
                kisiInfoList.clear();
                listeyiCek();
                adapter = new RehberListAdapter(RehberActivity.this, kisiInfoList);
                rehberListView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());

        }
    });
```

And here is a filter method that your adapter includes,

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                FilterResults results) {        

            if (results.count == 0)
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            else {
                kisiList = (List<Kisi>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                results.values = kisiList;
                results.count = kisiList.size();
            } else {
                List<Kisi> nPlanetList = new ArrayList<Kisi>();

                for (Kisi p : kisiList) {
                    if (p.getAdSoyad()
                            .toUpperCase()
                            .startsWith(constraint.toString().toUpperCase()))
                        nPlanetList.add(p);
                }

                results.values = nPlanetList;
                results.count = nPlanetList.size();

            }
            return results;
        }
    };
}
```

When you enter text it is filtering and restricting your listView

Comment: I tried this but I was getting error that the method is refering to non-static. I tried to adjust your example to my code, but unfortunately not with succes yet. I posted mine, maybe you can give me a hint. Thanks.

Comment: Use baseadapter instead of SimpleCursorAdapter.Because it is easy for future revisions.Also it will be execute